# How can I validate file size and file type errors?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a form with several inputs file, I am trying to validate the errors when uploading files so that you can not upload files larger than 200kb and with the desired extension, all with yup and formik, the method I have found makes the error no matter the size and extension of the file, someone could find the reason? I have simplified the form because it is very long, I am using react typescript.

```
////validationSchema
import * as yup from "yup";

const isRequiredMessage = "Completa este espacio";

var FILE_SIZE = 204800;
var SUPPORTED_FORMATS = ['image/jpg', 'image/jpeg', 'image/gif', 'image/png']

export default yup.object().shape({
    
    //validacion documentacion
    title: yup.mixed().required(isRequiredMessage),
    .test('fileSize', "File Size is too large", value => value.size <= FILE_SIZE).required(isRequiredMessage)
    .test('fileType', "Unsupported File Format", value => SUPPORTED_FORMATS.includes(value.type) )
    
    
});

///component form

import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Formik, Form, Field, ErrorMessage } from "formik";
import validationSchema from "../../validation-form-collegiate/validationSchema";
import { PictureInput } from './PictureInput'
import './register.css'

interface FormValues {
   
    //validacion documentacion
    title: null;
    
    }

export const RegistrationRequest = () => {

  const initialValues: FormValues = {
    
    //validacion documentacion
    title: null,
   
  };

  const onSubmit = (values: FormValues) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log(values)
      alert(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2));
    }, 500);
  };


  return (
    <>
     
           <Formik initialValues={initialValues} onSubmit={onSubmit} validationSchema={validationSchema} >  
            <Form>                                      
                      
                                    <Field name="title" component={PictureInput} className="block w-full text-xs text-gray-900 bg-gray-50 rounded-lg border border-gray-300 cursor-pointer my-2" id="file" type="file" />
                                    <ErrorMessage  name="title" component="span" className="mt-2 text-xs text-red-600"/>
                                    <p className="my-2 text-xs text-neutral-500">Adjuntar título Oficial de Fisioterapia (Diplomatura o Graduado)</p>
                                    <p className="my-2 text-xs text-neutral-500">Los archivos deben ser menores que <b>50MB</b>. Tipos de archivo permitidos: <b>.gif .jpg .jpeg .png .pdf</b>.</p>
                                               
                 </Form> 
                </Formik>
           </div>
    </>
  );
}
////component PictureInput
import React from "react";

export const PictureInput = ({ form, field }) => (
  <input
    name={field.name}
    type="file"
    accept="image/*"
    onChange={(e: React.FormEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
        const newValue = e.currentTarget.files;
        form.setFieldValue(field.name, newValue) }
    }
       
  />
);
```

Comment: Could you please include the type of error you're getting, and if possible, provide a minimal runnable example in a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) for example?

Comment: I do not receive any error, simply any file size triggers the validation error itself

Comment: Please add a code sandbox example, so I can help you.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/heuristic-frost-wi8i9t?file=/src/RegistrationRequest.tsx

Comment: in your validationSchema, tyep of ```value``` inside ```test``` callback is FIleList. get the first item from array and check it's size and type.

Comment: Could you show it in the code to make it clearer?

Comment: ```yup.mixed().required(isRequiredMessage)
.test("fileSize","File Size is too large",(value) => value[0].size <= FILE_SIZE)
.test("fileType", "Unsupported File Format", (value) => SUPPORTED_FORMATS.includes(value[0].type))```

Comment: I have encountered an error when adding the other file fields, do you know where the error is. I have modified the code in sanbox. error: Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read properties of null (reading '0')

Comment: how to debug: inside the callback of ```test``` function, do ```console.log(value)```  then return whatever your condition is.

Comment: solution: your ```value``` inside test callback of registration field is null, so accessing it's index is giving error. check for null before accessing it's index.

you may encounter a lot of trivial errors like this as i have never used yup. please learn to debug them or maybe some expert/experienced can help you further.

Comment: I understand what you are saying, I found this solution and adapted it to my code and it worked, thanks again.

Comment: file: mixed()
    .test('fileSize', 'File too large', (value) => value === null || (value && value.size <= FILE_SIZE))
    .test(
      'fileFormat',
      'Unsupported file type',
      (value) => value === null || (value && SUPPORTED_FORMATS.includes(value.type))